# PHP form validation not working, allowing invalid submissions to be sent

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have written a script mail.php to handle the validation of form data and to send the form data via email. I have been testing this script by entering known invalid data however the script does not echo the error messages and just sends the data anyway.

Here is the form html:

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php" class="col-12" id="form-book">
            <div class="row">
              <div class=" form-group col-12">
                <p>Fill out the form below to tell me about your problem. <strong>Any problems to do with technology, all the solutions.</strong> Just tell me what you can, however the more info you give the better.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-6">
                <label></label>
                <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required="required" class="form-control here bottom"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $nameErr; echo $nameErrEmpty;?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-6">
                <label></label>
                <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone#" type="text" required="required" class="form-control here bottom"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $phoneErr; echo$phoneErrEmpty;?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label></label>
                <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email (Optional)" type="text" class="form-control here bottom"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr; echo $emailErrEmpty;?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-6">
                <input data-provide="datepicker" id="date" name="date" placeholder="Pick a date" required="required" class="form-control here bottom"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $dateErr; echo $dateErrEmpty;?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-6">
                <input type="text" id="time" name="time" placeholder="Choose the best time" required="required" class="form-control here bottom timepicker"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $timeErr; echo $timeErrEmpty;?></span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-12">
                <label></label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="40" rows="5" class="form-control" required="required" aria-describedby="messageHelpBlock"></textarea> <span class="error"> <?php echo $messageErr; echo $messageErrEmpty;?></span>
                <span id="messageHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">Tell me a little about whats going on or what you need help with.</span>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-12">
                <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send your message</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--row-->
          </form>
```

Here is mail.php:

```
        <?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    set_error_handler("var_dump");

    date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Honolulu");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $time = $_POST['time'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = "Appointment Booked";

    $mailTo = "itguy@johnpuaoi.com";

    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
    }


    if (empty($name)) {
    $nameErrEmpty = "Your name is required";
    } elseif (is_int($name)) {
    $nameErr = "That is not a valid name";
    } else {
    $nameTested = test_input($name);
    }

    if (empty($phone)) {
    $phoneErrEmpty = "Your phone number is required";
    } elseif (is_int($name)) {
    $phoneTested = test_input($phone);
    } else {
    $phoneErr = "Phone Number needs to be in this format e.x 1234567890";
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
    $emailErrEmpty = "Your name is required";
    } elseif (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailErr = "That is not a valid email";
    } else {
    $emailTested = test_input($name);
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
    $messageErrEmpty ="You must tell me about your problem";
    } else {
    $messageTested = test_input($message);
    }


    $dateTested = test_input($date);
    $timeTested = test_input($time);

    $headers = "From: ".$emailTested;
    $txt = "An appointment was booked by ".$nameTested.".\n\n".$dateTested." @".$timeTested.".\n\n".$messageTested;

    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: index.php?mailsend");
    }
    ?>
```

I have searched stack for similar issues but have found none. I am a total noob to php so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe because you are not echoing anything ? Even if there is an error, you don't have anything that blocks the script.

Comment: hmm well in mail.php I am not echoing anything but in my html I have put php code next to the <inputs>. So in mail.php if there is an invalid submission, an error variable is created. In the php thats embedded into the html it echos the error variable that was created when the script detected there was an invalid submission.

Comment: You will always hit the `mail` and then `header` lines of code. There is no part in the validation process that will stop that from happening. You probably need to check whether there's an error before mailing.